# kubernetes liveliness is un-authorized

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes

I am trying to define a livenessProbe by passing the value of httpheader as secret. but I am getting un-authorized 401.

```
  - name: mycontainer
    image: myimage
    env:
      - name: MY_SECRET
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: actuatortoken
            key: token
    livenessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /test/actuator/health
          port: 9001
          httpHeaders:
          - name: Authorization
            value: $MY_SECRET
```

My secret as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: actuatortoken
type: Opaque
stringData:
  token: Bearer <token>
```

If I pass the same with actual value as below... it works as expected

```
  - name: mycontainer
    image: myimage
    livenessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /test/actuator/health
          port: 9001
          httpHeaders:
          - name: Authorization
            value: Bearer <token>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: if you exec inside the container and execute echo $MY_SECRET what does it show?

Comment: What you have will put the literal string `$MY_SECRET` as the Authorization header which won't work. You don't want to put the actual value of the secret in your Pod/Deployment/whatever YAML since you don't want plaintext credentials in there. 3 options I can think of: (a) change your app to not require authentication for the `/test/actuator/health` endpoint; (b) change your app to not require authentication when the requested host is `127.0.0.1` and update the probe configuration to use that as the host; (c) switch from an HTTP probe to a command probe and write the curl/wget command yourself

Comment: I agree with @AmitKumarGupta on this toughs. Please AmitKumarGupta write an answer.

Comment: This is a common thing, you don't need auth for your readiness endpoint. If you don't want to expose the actuator endpoint outside of the container, just configure it to serve on a different endpoint and it will only be accessible to the health probes

Answer (score 0):

What you have will put the literal string `$MY_SECRET` as the Authorization header which won't work.

You don't want to put the actual value of the secret in your Pod/Deployment/whatever YAML since you don't want plaintext credentials in there.

3 options I can think of:

a) change your app to not require authentication for the `/test/actuator/health` endpoint;

b) change your app to not require authentication when the requested host is `127.0.0.1` and update the probe configuration to use that as the host;

c) switch from an HTTP probe to a command probe and write the curl/wget command yourself

**Answer is being posted as Community wiki as it's from [Amit Kumar Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1061413/amit-kumar-gupta) comments.**